# Where did the phrase "you're welcome" come from?

Tags: etymology

"You're welcome" as a response to "thank you" makes absolutely no sense. You're welcome to what?

Comment: Cross-reference: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279498/is-english-the-only-language-to-use-youre-welcome

Answer (score 7):

The first references to welcome are found in *Beowolf*.

By 1300, “welcome” was being used more loosely to describe something acceptable, pleasurable, freely permitted, or cordially invited.

From Othello: (circa 1603):

> Lodovico: Madam, good night; I humbly thank your ladyship.
>   Desdemona: Your honour is **most welcome**.

From the linked source:

> A reader found an earlier citation in The House by the Churchyard, an 1863 novel by the Irish writer Sheridan Le Fanu: “ ‘I thank ye again, sir.’ ‘You’re welcome, my honey,’ rejoined Toole, affectionately.”

I don't find it at all mysterious. I imagine it like

> *You have done well to come to me; I am pleased to do it.*

I was taught to say it. In French, they say *avec plaisir* (with pleasure) or *de rien* (it's nothing), in Spanish, *con gusto* (with pleasure) or *de nada* (it's nothing.) *

([Source](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/07/welcoming-committee.html))

*<sub>In the part of Quebec where my parents were born, "Bienvenu" (you're welcome) was the response to "thank you". I actually never heard "de rien" until I was in France, although I don't know what the answer is in Montreal.</sub>

Comment: Interesting. I think there is another way to understand it. You are welcome would be *You are welcome to my help* using help as a noun, in a similar way that we could say *(You are) welcome to our home*: that is something we are pleased to do/to happen. It fits your translation into spanish as *Con gusto* although it is usually translated as meaning *it was nothing* (de nada).

Comment: @santimirandarp - I agree that *de nada* and *de rien* are very common responses to "Thank you". I myself would say *de nada* when speaking Spanish with Hispanics at work. It's a lot like the English answers, "Not at all/no problem/It's nothing."

Comment: Yes, and it means that the common translation of you are welcome as de nada is wrong. I have added an answer. Not sure if it is right but just another point of view.

Comment: @santimirandarp translation is often not word for word or even for denotational equivalence. For things like phaticisms, they're often just meaningless mantras that are elicited automatically in the social context. It's just what you are supposed to say, little more.

Comment: @Mitch usually when that happens there is a historical explanation. For example *By heart* meant *from memory* because the heart was thinking as the house of memory...In this case, you are welcome is historically related to welcome, in my opinion.

Comment: @santimirandarp There is no doubt that the word welcome slid over slightly in meaning. I was addressing your statement that 'the common translation of you're welcome as da nada is wrong' is wrong. A close translation, trying to preserve word translations from English into Spanish would give you something in Spanish that translated back, in the same style, no English speaker word ever consider saying. And translating 'da nada', has many socially equivalent alternatives in English including 'you're welcome'

Comment: @Mitch hmm..I see. Well I don't think that *de nada* is completely wrong and I think we have a similar idea about translation. Look at the answer  I added.

Comment: @Mitch you say we must to translate meanings, and sometimes the meaning is different from word by word translation. Right, I agree. But I would add that when that happens, there is a quite interesting issue to investigate historically.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually a sensible response to *thank you*.  All you have to do is look at the modern replacements for it.

When someone thanks me, I'm often wont to say "No problem!" as my response.  Or, "It was my pleasure." and so on.

The welcome in *you're welcome* is a statement saying:  *I would do this for you again, if asked."  (*i.e.* You're welcome to ask me again.)  See Susan's excellent answer for the origins and evolving usages of the word *welcome*.

Now, this may or not be a true statement.  If someone thanks you for donating a kidney, and you hazily say "You're welcome!"  I do not believe that anyone would think you would happily donate the other kidney.

But, on the other hand.  A think a thank you for a larger favor rarely elicits a simple *you're welcome* in response.  Rather, after donating a kidney, one would probably gush on about how this person is an important part of their life and they couldn't bear to stand by whilst they were dying, and so-on.

In short:  You're welcome to accept this as the correct answer.  And, if you do, I will thank you.

Comment: where is susan's excellent answer?

Comment: @santimirandarp - That would be me before name change. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. So David was right...;) @anongoodnurse

Answer (score 2):

From [this etymonline entry](https://www.etymonline.com/word/welcome), about welcome:

> Old English wilcuma "welcome!" exclamation of kindly greeting, from
>   earlier wilcuma (n.) "welcome guest," literally "one whose coming
>   suits another's will or wish,"

So in both, when you say *welcome* (home) or *you are welcome* (to my help) there is an implication of pleasure. I think that's the key: think of both as related to pleasure.

It fits the translation of *welcome* as *bienvenido* and *you are welcome* as *con gusto* as said in one previous answer, because they are related to pleasure.

**Sidenote**

In spanish language you are welcome is also translated as *It was nothing*, but seems not to be the proper translation. Another explanation can be that *You are welcome* has changed its meaning from *It was a pleasure* to *It was nothing*.

Comment: +1 for "Another explanation can be that You are welcome has changed its meaning from It was a pleasure to It was nothing."

Answer (score 0):

[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/welcome) gives two relevant definitions for the adjective:

- giving pleasure :  received with gladness or delight especially in response to a need ("a welcome relief")

and, probably more relevant

- willingly permitted or admitted ("he was welcome to come and go" — W. M. Thackeray)

The implication of "you're welcome" in response to "thank you" is that the action for which the thanking party is grateful was willingly and happily given -- it was a pleasure on the part person being thanked.